# Presenting a View Controller after login

Tags: ios, objective-c

I recently started a new project and after I successfully set up a login page, I came into a problem.

If I type in valid credentials in the text fields, my app should do the following:

```
if (user) {
    [self.delegate loginViewControllerDidLogin:self];
    ...
```

The "if user" part means that everything was okay. After a few hours of searching I got to know that my `[self.delegate loginViewControllerDidLogin:self];` should be defined in the `AppDelegate.m` file. Here I wrote the following code:

```
- (void)loginViewControllerDidLogin:(LoginViewController *)controller {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController * ViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    [self.window addSubview:ViewController.view];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:ViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

My problem is that I cannot define the ViewController on my story board, so I cannot connect the code with the ViewController itself.

So basically I would like the app to open a new ViewController after logging in.

Comment: Why can't you define the ViewController on your storyboard?

Comment: I don't know how to... tried it in the ViewController.h, but even after I imported the it to the AppDelegates.m file it just couldn't recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

On your storyboard select the view controller you want to display and fill out the "Storyboard ID":
[image]

Then instantiate it like this:

```
  UIViewController * ViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourVCStoryboardID"];
```